# Placing video content into a sidebar

Tags: sidebar

I'm trying to figure out how to place video from a post (category video) into a sidebar. I can get other content content images and text to show, I'm guessing it has something to do with post format? If I lable the post formet as video then there must be a call for it.

so far I have:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => 5, 'post_type' =>  'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );    
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
<div class="sidebar_thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'sidebar_thumbnail' ); ?></div>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>      
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- end sidebar video posts -->

<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>...
```

but insead of the thumbnail image link to the post I'd rather have the video from the post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a meta field along with your post which contains image/video fram url. Now write a plugin or some PHP code which access particular meta tag of a post. And display it.
2. As an alternative you can use some plugin like [amtyThumb](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amtythumb/)